# How to test/train split by column value rather than by row in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to generate a train and test set for machine learning.  Let's say I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
account_id | session_id | feature_1 | feature_2 | label
```

In this dataset, each row will have a unique session_id, but an account_id can show up multiple times.  However, I want my train and test sets to have mutually exclusive account_ids.  (Almost seems like the opposite of stratified sampling).

In pandas, this is simple enough.  I have something like the following:

```
def train_test_split(df, split_col, feature_cols, label_col, test_fraction=0.2):
    """
    While sklearn train_test_split splits by each row in the dataset,
    this function will split by a specific column. In that way, we can 
    separate account_id such that train and test sets will have mutually
    exclusive accounts, to minimize cross-talk between train and test sets.
    """
    split_values = df[split_col].drop_duplicates()
    test_values = split_values.sample(frac=test_fraction, random_state=42)
    
    df_test = df[df[split_col].isin(test_values)]
    df_train = df[~df[split_col].isin(test_values)]

    return df_test, df_train
```

Now, my dataset is large enough that it cannot fit into memory, and I have to switch over from pandas to doing all of this in pyspark.  How can I split a train and test set to have mutually exclusive account_ids in pyspark, without fitting everything into memory?

Comment: For mutually exclusive account_id for train and test datasets, find account_ids and their respective counts. With that info, you can determine which account_ids has to be chosen for training and test.

The ratio is 80/20 or 70/30 right? If so, then find a combination of account_id that make up 80/20 or 70/30 roughly.

You didn't mention where the data is located? Parquet/ S3 etc. Once you figure out account_id that correspond to Train, Test, you can use Spark APIs to read the data directly avoiding Pandas DF to Spark DF conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rand()` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` for generating a random number for each of the **distinct** `account_id` and create `train` and `test` dataframes based on this random number.

```
from psypark.sql import functions as F

TEST_FRACTION = 0.2

train_test_split = (df.select("account_id")
                      .distinct()  # removing duplicate account_ids
                      .withColumn("rand_val", F.rand())
                      .withColumn("data_type", F.when(F.col("rand_val") < TEST_FRACTION, "test")
                                                .otherwise("train")))

train_df = (train_test_split.filter(F.col("data_type") == "train")
                            .join(df, on="account_id"))  # inner join removes all rows other than train

test_df = (train_test_split.filter(F.col("data_type") == "test")
                           .join(df, on="account_id"))
```

Since an `account_id` cannot be both `train` and `test` at a time, `train_df` and `test_df` will have mutually exclusive `account_id`s.

Comment: You haven't solved this aspect of the problem `However, I want my train and test sets to have mutually exclusive account_ids.`

Comment: @user238607 Since `train_test_split` will have one and only one row for each `account_id` and each row is either `train` or `test` according to the `data_type` column, an `account_id` can be either `train` or `test`, but not both. Since an `account_id` cannot be both `train` and `test` at a time, `train_df` and `test_df` will have mutually exclusive `account_id`s.

Comment: @Safwan, can you provide a reference to your statement? [This](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) documentation is not clear.