# Train / Eval / Test split based on a column value PySpark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark

I want to do a train / eval / test split on my spark dataframe, based on the "code" column. Rows with a same "code" value should be in the same set (train, eval or test). So no "code" should appear in more than one of the sets.

```
def train_eval_test_split(df, EVAL_FRACTION=0.15, TEST_FRACTION=0.15):
    train_test_split = (
        df.select("code")
        .distinct()
        .withColumn("rand_val", F.rand(seed=42))
        .withColumn(
            "data_type",
            F.when(F.col("code").isin(codes_to_put_in_train), "train")
            .when(F.col("code").isin(codes_to_put_in_eval), "eval")
            .when(F.col("code").isin(codes_to_put_in_test), "test")
            .when(F.col("rand_val") < TEST_FRACTION, "test")
            .when(
                (F.col("rand_val") >= TEST_FRACTION)
                & (F.col("rand_val") < TEST_FRACTION + EVAL_FRACTION),
                "eval",
            )
            .otherwise("train"),
        )
    )

    train_df = train_test_split.filter(F.col("data_type") == "train").join(
        df, on="code"
    )  # inner join removes all rows other than train

    test_df = train_test_split.filter(F.col("data_type") == "test").join(df, on="code")

    eval_df = train_test_split.filter(F.col("data_type") == "eval").join(df, on="code")


return train_df, eval_df, test_df
```

(NB: codes_to_put_in_train, codes_to_put_in_eval, codes_to_put_in_test are codes list that I want to manually force into the corresponding sets)

Sadly when I sanity check the results some codes are both in train_df and test_df (or other combination)

I based my code on this answer [How to test/train split by column value rather than by row in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709218/how-to-test-train-split-by-column-value-rather-than-by-row-in-pyspark)

Comment: [sampleBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy)

Comment: No :/ I want each set to have distinct codes so it's kind of the opposite of a stratify operation

Answer (score 0):

```
    unique_codes = df[["code"]].distinct()
    train_codes, eval_codes, test_codes = unique_codes.randomSplit([0.7, 0.15, 0.15], seed=42)
    
    train_set = df.join(train_codes, on="code")
    eval_set = df.join(eval_codes, on="code")
    test_set = df.join(test_codes, on="code")
```

If useful to anyone I finally found a simple implementation